# What is the difference between '>' and '#' is command line interface in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am a beginner in using Linux and have almost completed the basic of Linux. I always wondered what is the difference between '>' and '#' in cli.

```
abc@localhost>
```

and

```
xyz@localhost#
```

Answer (score 2):

`#` usually determines a superuser shell (with root access rights), while `%` or `$` are used for non-privileged shells started by non-root users.

`>` is usually the continuation prompt for incomplete command lines.

This is all by convention and can be customized through different mechanisms, depending on the shell.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wanted an answer that precise.

Comment: in addition, > usually signifies the line entry is the continuation of a previously incomplete line

Answer (score 0):

No different at all but on some shells # is used for the user with root privilege .